# How to permanently delete entries from MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

This article suggests way of recovering data in a MYSQL db:  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/02/20/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-an-innodb-tablespace/

How can we delete sensitive information and ensure it is not recoverable using any methods such as the one described in the article above?  Also interested in just row deletion instead of entire tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

To permanently delete the tables from mysql so that its not recoverable(upto some extent).do the following.

```
1.delete the InnoDB main table space – ibdata1 – and redo logs – ib_logfile*.
2.restart mysql after step 1.
```

Comment: What if it is only certain rows instead of entire tables?

Comment: sorry i dont have much idea about rows but what i know is if the main table space and logfile is there than anybody can recover your data.